# Is the cosine similarity of the average vector same as the average of the cosine similarities?

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, cosine-similarity

I have a vector `v` which I want to compare with a set of vectors `U = [u1, u2, u3 ...]`.
I want to find the average cosine similarity of `v` with all vectors in `U`.

My first thought was to compute:

```
s1 = cosine_similarity(v, u1) 
s2 = cosine_similarity(v, u2) 
...
```

and then take the average as

```
s = np.mean([s1, s2, s3 ...])
```

But I was wondering if this process is the same as just taking the average of U to get a single vector u and then compute

```
u = np.mean(U)
s = cosine_similarity(x, u)
```

Are the results the same in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take a simple example and check if the results are the same. Short answer, no.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

x1 = np.random.rand(1, 100)
x2 = np.random.rand(1, 100)

y = np.random.rand(1, 100)

print(cosine_similarity(x1, y) + cosine_similarity(x2, y))

m = x1+x2
print(cosine_similarity(m, y))
```